# Record audio from YouTube videos

Tags: audio, media-converter, mp3, youtube

This is not about downloading YouTube videos.

I used to record YouTube videos as WAV while they were playing in my browser and then convert to MP3 on my laptop with jetAudio. But now I have an old PC which doesn't let me do that. I tried jetAudio but no luck, I guess it's because of the built-in sound card.

Any other programs you know that may let you do that? And doing so I think it's legal since I'm not downloading them.

Comment: Why did you do the hard way? You can download the .mp3 version of the video instead. Application/program like that exists out there.

Comment: But it's illegal, youtube was designed as an online experience and downloading videos is illegal, I know there are services that convert YT videos into mp3, but I don't know how legal is that, I'm pretty sure it's illegal.

Comment: *an old PC* How about specifying that? Please [edit] your question and include OS, price you are willing to pay, etc.  http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: And if you are sure converting YT video to mp3 it is illegal, why do your method is legal?

Comment: Because when I just record the sound while the video is playing in my browser the video itself is still an online experience as per Youtube user agreement and it is not being manipulated or used directly to extract the sound. It is not what I think is legal or illegal, it is what the user agreement says into which you enter anytime you visit YT.

Comment: Could you give your sound card specs? If it has an audio input, you could try connecting it to the speaker output via [**such a cable**](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41IKN5qK7PL.jpg)

Comment: Concerning the legality issue, what you're doing is no less illegal than downloading, so you might as well save yourself the trouble and try a downloader. The [**terms of service**](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms?gl=US) clearly say: `You shall not copy, reproduce, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, or otherwise exploit any Content [...]`. I think recording falls under the `copy` or `reproduce` umbrella terms

Comment: Hm, could well be, but my understanding is that if I downloaded a video and made a copy of it, that's copying. I'm just recording the sound my computer emits while the video is playing. 

If record a sound of a TV show via TV speakers does it mean I'm copying that TV show? I'll do some more research.

Comment: @MarinaDunst That sound may be emitted by your computer, but the source it still the video. It doesn't matter which device the sound comes out of - what matters is the source, which in this case is a YouTube video. It doesn't matter whether you're using one of the various "Convert YouTube to mp3" websites, or whether you're recording the audio and converting it afterwards - ultimately the sound still comes from the same source: the YouTube video.  
Thus, both ways go against YouTube's terms of service.

And yes, recording the sound of a TV show is copying (the sound of) that TV show.

Answer (score 2):

There is a marvellous command line program/python library called [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) which will let you download and convert to audio only from youtube & other sites.

Available for multiple platforms as written in python but there is a [windows executable](https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.exe) that includes python. You may also need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29) and [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and have FFMPEG on your path or in the same directory as the youtube-dl executable.

For audio only simply call as: `youtube-dl -x --audio-format MP3` *url_of_item*

e.g.:

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otXGqU4LBEI
```

Would download and convert leaving you with: `"I would walk 500 miles - The Proclaimers-otXGqU4LBEI.mp3"`

*The question of the legality of keeping such material is subject to the original material, the country you are in, the use the you make of it, etc., etc., ad nauseam*.